# How do I convert two columns of integers into one column of dates so I can plot it on a graph

Tags: r, date

I'm looking at the "airquality" dataframe in R and I'm wondering how to convert the Month/Day columns into dates so I can plot them on a graph. In the picture below is a plot I did when I didn't know airquality had a month column as well. (Basically, how do I convert two columns of integers into one column of dates so I can plot it on a graph without making it look like poop)

**Plot**

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2):

Dates need a year, so we can pick one arbitrarily:

```
aq = airquality
aq$date = as.Date(paste("2020", aq$Month, aq$Day, sep = "-"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aq, aes(x = date, y = Ozone)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think I was making it too complicated when trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tidyverse and lubridate, we can do all what you wanted with 1 single command, we load the dataset, add the year 1973 as that's what year the data was collected. create a new column for the entire date and send that to ggplot2 to graph. if you get errors for Ozone having NA values you can use the `remove_missing()` functino from *ggplot2*

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)




airquality %>% mutate(Year = 1973) %>% 
mutate(date = make_datetime(Year, Month, Day)) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = date, y = Ozone))
```

[image]